# IOS date returns null

Tags: ios, date, null

I have date in object "start_time"(2000-12-11T00:00:00+0000), but i need to print date and time separate to textfields. But when i tried with this code i got null value on console

```
        __block NSDictionary *events = [[e.response objectForKey:@"events"] objectAtIndex:0];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
          //  NSDate *dates = [events objectForKey:@"start_time"];
          //  NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] init];
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMMM dd yyyy";
            NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [events objectForKey:@"start_time"]];
            NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] init];
            timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss ZZZZ";
            NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate: [events objectForKey:@"start_time"]];





           NSLog(@"This is time------------------------------: %@",dateString);    // null returns
```

//
This is how i store date into "start_time" by textfields

Blockquote

```
    NSString *datestring = self.date.text;
    NSString *timestring = self.time.text;
    NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", datestring, timestring];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:05.30]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM dd yyyy HH:mm a"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:combined];
    NSDictionary *data = @{
    @"start_time":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date]};
```

Comment: don't do the double "`init`" thing you're doing.  You only need one `[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];`

Comment: it is still returns null

Comment: Actullay i want to print date and time separate into two textfields.

Comment: Are you sure start_time is `NSDate` object

Comment: Yes. and also         NSLog(@"This is it------------------------------: %@",[events objectForKey:@"start_time"]);
 gives (2000-12-11T00:00:00+0000) but i want these date and time separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that became `null` Because you upcoming date from event that is different format and you are first setting format is different.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMMM dd yyyy";
```

that have to:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
```

You have to set first current date format then you can change it your want date.

Comment: No it still have same null value

Answer (score 0):

Your setting an incorrect format for the date,

Try the below, this will work

```
 //"myDate" variable is an example string, you can change it with "[events objectForKey:@"start_time"]"
NSString *myDate = @"2000-12-11T00:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-dd-mm'T'HH:mm:ss Z";
NSDate *myDateObject = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate]; //Now you have the date object that return the correct value


//FOR date

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-mm"];
NSString *OnlyDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDateObject];

//For Time

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *OnlyTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDateObject];


NSLog(@"Date is %@ and Time is %@",OnlyDate,OnlyTime);
```

**UPDATE**

In your case, if [events objectForKey:@"start_time"] is a NSDATE object then try the following

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-dd-mm'T'HH:mm:ss Z";
NSDate *myDateObject = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[events objectForKey:@"start_time"]]; //Now you have the date object that return the correct value


//FOR date

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-mm"];
NSString *OnlyDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDateObject];

//For Time

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *OnlyTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDateObject];


NSLog(@"Date is %@ and Time is %@",OnlyDate,OnlyTime);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i use                 NSString *myDate = [events objectForKey:@"start_time"]; instead of NSString *myDate = @"2000-12-11T00:00:00 +0000";
get null value on console for both OnlyDate,OnlyTime

Comment: ARE YOU SURE,[events objectForKey:@"start_time"] is an NSDATE object and not NSSTRING

Comment: I would suggest you to bring it as a string object, and then do the above on it.

Comment: Yes its NSDate object.When i try to convert it to string always getting null value.

Comment: This is the code i used to store date into "start_time" by textfields. Hopes now you get complete picture

Comment: NSString *datestring = self.date.text;
    NSString *timestring = self.time.text;
    NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", datestring, timestring];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:05.30]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM dd yyyy HH:mm a"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:combined];
    NSDictionary *data = @{
    @"start_time":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date],

Comment: Thats my point, instead of converting it into NSDATE object here, you should keep it as string, which is variable "combined" in your code. then use my above code, done!

Comment: But i want to store combined string as date and store into "start_time" and then retrieve from it and need to dispaly on textfield by clicking an update button. This is the real purpose. date should be in the fomat date filed "March 22 2012" and time field "1:11 AM GMT+5.30"